# GLOB htmlentities() error

Tags: glob

I want to use GLOB to get all images from a directory, but I keep getting an htmlentities() error.

htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

My code:

**VIEW:**

```
@extends('layouts.templates.master')

@section('content')

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <img class="header-image" width="100%" height="200px"  src="/assets/events/training.jpg" />
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="page-title">FOTO'S</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @foreach($images as $image)
                <h3 style="color: white;font-family:'Michroma',sans-serif;">{{ $image->title }}</h3>

            {{{ $fotos = glob($image->img_folder . "/*.jpg") }}}
            @foreach( $fotos as $foto )
                <a href="{{ $foto }}" class="fullsizable">
                    <img src="{{ $foto }}">
                </a>
            @endforeach

            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
@stop
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php

Class ImagesController extends BaseController
{
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $images = Images::where('slug', '=', $slug)->get();

        return View::make('layouts.images.imagegallery')->with('images', $images);
    }

    public function all(){
        $images = Images::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

        return View::make('layouts.images.imageslist')->with('images', $images);
    }
}
```

This is my code, hope you can help me

Comment: where do you use `htmlentities()`? can you post more code?

Comment: I'm not using htmlentities anywhere

Comment: sure? maybe within `dd()`?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, even when I replace dd() with <img src="{{ $foto }}"> I get the same error message.

Comment: That can not be all of your code.

Comment: I updated the post with my code